# Angular 5 Update View From Within While Loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a progress bar in my app that updates using a while loop. I can successfully change the update progress value with each loop, but the view only updates after the whole while loop has completed. Is there any way to add something in the while loop like "ForceViewUpdate()" on each loop, or something like that?

Check my example here and open the console to see the values being updated:
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5zlja4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way in which you wait blocks the entire jsvascript thread. Javascript runs on a single thread if you block that thread running a `while` loop you will not let any other code get executed, including UI updates. You should use `setTimeout` to  run code after a time, or, you can use `aync/await` and `Promises` to give your code a more sequential feel:

```
export class AppComponent  {
    sStatus = "Inactive";
    iProgressMax = 100;
    iProgressValue = 0;

  async Run() {
    this.sStatus = "Running...";
    while (this.iProgressValue < this.iProgressMax) {
      await this.wait(1000);
      this.iProgressValue = this.iProgressValue + 20;
      console.log(this.iProgressValue);
    }
    this.sStatus = "Complete";
  }

  wait(ms: number)  {
    return new Promise((resolve)=> {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Love getting a perfect answer right away :)

Comment: @Frank I try :)